# Why won't StackPanel put textblock on left and button on right in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, stackpanel

OK, I give up: what do I have to change to this **StackPanel** below so that it puts the:

- text on far left of form
- **button on far right of form**.

[alt text http://tanguay.info/web/external/stackPanelLeftRight.png](http://tanguay.info/web/external/stackPanelLeftRight.png)

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestData333.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="400" Height="300">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Yellow" Padding="20">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ScrollViewer Background="Beige" 
                              Height="230"
                              Width="360">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TheContent" 
                           Foreground="Navy"
                           FontSize="14"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ProgressIndicator" Text="Ready..."
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <Button Content="Load Data"
                        Width="100"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Click="Button_Load"
                        Margin="0 5 0 0"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

## ANSWER:

Downloaded [Silverlight 3 toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%201) which has DockPanel, installed, referenced System.Windows.Controls, then following XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestData333.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
    Width="400" Height="300">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Yellow" Padding="20">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ScrollViewer Background="Beige" 
                              Height="230"
                              Width="360">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TheContent" 
                           Foreground="Navy"
                           FontSize="14"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>

                <toolkit:DockPanel Margin="0 5 0 0">
                    <TextBlock toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="ProgressIndicator" Text="Ready..."
                               FontSize="12"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <Button toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Load Data"
                        Width="100"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Click="Button_Load"/>
                </toolkit:DockPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[alt text http://tanguay.info/web/external/silverlightDockPanel.png](http://tanguay.info/web/external/silverlightDockPanel.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could use dockpanel from toolkit or use grid with 2 columns. and have the content of the second column right aligned

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean that you want the button aligned to the right of the form? If so, StackPanel won't do that. It's made to "stack things up" either horizontally or vertically.

I would suggest you try [DockPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx):

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="ProgressIndicator" 
               DockPanel.Dock="Left"
               Text="Ready..." />
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            Content="Load Data"
            Width="100"
            Click="Button_Load"
            Margin="0,5,0,0" />
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: yes, that's the way I do it in WPF but I'm using Silverlight at the moment, albeit Silverlight 3, sorry to see there's no dockpanel in this version, searching for some workaround...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Silverlight control toolkit has a dockpanel

Comment: Silverlight doesn't have a DockPanel? I have to pay more attention to questions' tags. I automatically assumed it was a WPF question, but I had no idea that there was no DockPanel in Silverlight!

Answer (score 1):

I think Matt's approach it the best. Two alternatives though are to use a grid and align the content to the left and right or to just give the button a really large margin.

Answer (score 1):

Reference should be:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
```